# Returning false on event prevents event occuring afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background**
I have a bootstrap modal that pop ups and display input forms, if the user makes changes and cancels/closes the modal a confirm box will identify they will lose changes.

The modal fires two events, `hide` when the modal begins closing and `hidden` when the modal is completely closed.

I'm intercepting the `hide` event with:

```
.on('hide',function(){
    if(confirm('close'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

If I close the box and hit Ok, the modal will close.

If I hit cancel the modal will stay open (which is correct) but I will hit Ok after it will not continue the default event.

- hit OK (works)
- hit Cancel (works)
- hit OK after hitting Cancel (fails)

I have tried `preventDefault();` as well but I cannot figure out how to get the event to continue after a Cancel action.

Can be tested here:

http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

Enter in console:

`$('#responsive').on('hide', function() { if(confirm('close)) return true; else return false;});`

Comment: Seems like you're saying there's a bug in the modal code.

Comment: @cookiemonster I wouldn't say its the modal code, the confirm dialog isn't normally there - I'm just using on event to intercept the close it to add a confirm box

Comment: It's the modal code that's defining the `hide` event and responding to the return value, isn't it?

Comment: @cookiemonster your right, I found the issue - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diving into the source code of modal manager in bootstrap-modal.js line 84 of the hide function:

```
e && e.preventDefault();
e = $.Event('hide');
this.$element.trigger(e);
if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return (this.isShown = false); <-- 
this.isShown = false;
this.escape();
this.tab();
```

this.isShown is set to false causing a constant loop, it should be set to true since the modal isn't hidden when you fire e.preventDefault(). So the fix is:

```
if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return (this.isShown = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Are you attaching the .on('hide') event to the modal element? For example:

```
$('.modal').on('hide', function(){...});
```

I tested your code in JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5kbXZ/) using the example markup for a modal from Bootstrap 3 and it is working for me in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Using the latest version with modal manager, I've attached a link to the the authors site where you can test it through console. edit: interesting it works maybe the order of events or the modal manager then. thank you!